# How to automatically hide a modal popup control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model pop extender control like:

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="basketPopUp" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="Panel1" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" 
    Drag="true" 
    BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"
    TargetControlID="Panel1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Style="display: none" runat="server">
    <div class="PopupBody">
        <b>Test</b>
        <br />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

What i want is to show the popup for 5 seconds and HIDE it AUTOMATICALLY after this period of time.

I've tried this, but, running on the server side, of course it is not working:

```
 public void showAndHidePopUp()
{
    basketPopUp.Show();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    basketPopUp.Hide();
}
```

Do you know how to hide it in a proper way?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

For announcementes i've decided to use jGrowl-> http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html

and not ModalPopUp Extender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a javascript timer, let the client handle it:

http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/timer.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp